# How to get Receiving and Sent Data Byte Per Sec from SNMP

Tags: linux, snmp

Now I can get Total Receiving and Total  Sent from SNMP already

I want to get Receiving and Sent (Byte per Second) by SNMP

Help Me Pls.

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/0b5/shxqpG.png

Answer (score 1):

By reading `ifInOctets` and `ifOutOctets` from the `IF-MIB` (with *OID* `.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.`). As they contain only the total number of octets send/received you have to wait a short amount, query the information again and finally calculate the octets per second from your results.

This can be done for example via `snmpget ip-address IF-MIB::ifInOctets`. Debian ships the `snmpget`, `snmpwalk` etc. commands with the `snmp` package.